# After install tensorflow in virtualenv, the vscode says the module is not found [ubuntu20.04 ]

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, pip, virtualenv

### I install tensorflow in virtualenv through pip.

#### (my virtual environment's name is "object_venv")

[image]

code is like that.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


print(tf.__version__)
```

code is very simple. It is just for checking  tensorflow's version.

So run debugging, error message is

### "no module named "tensorflow"

[image]

Activate virtualenv, pip list alreday has tensorflow.

How do I refer to the **pip list package** installed in my virtual environment?

Comment: "*How do I refer to the **pip list package** installed in my virtual environment?*" By running `python` and `pip` from that venv: `path/to/vevn/bin/python -m pip list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On visual studio code, you need to make sure that vs code is using the same version of python as your virtual environment. See [here for how to change the python version on VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).